# can not generate Deployment Descriptor

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, deployment, eclipse-neon

In eclipse neon 2. I am trying to generate Deployment Descriptor of spring hibernate project. but I can't succeed.
I am trying to add it from java ee tools. but the option is disabled.

[image]

Suggest me how to get Deployment Descriptor.

Comment: Are you referring to web.xml for Maven Project?

Comment: yes. if you want then I can post a code.

Comment: you can create a new xml file under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml and add <web-app> and required namespaces

Comment: I already configure web.xml with welcome-page and servlet.

Comment: What is issue then? Can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: I restarted my eclipse, then eclipse shows the startup error:"An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for dms2(project).".
java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: ok after error shows, it was works for me.thanks

Comment: Included the image, people should not have to click!

Comment: I was tried. but I can post only image link. @Fabien

Answer (score -1):

You have to select proper maven project template while creating maven project from eclipse: 
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/UPM32/Creating+a+Simple+Maven+Project